# Convenient way to remove a particular tag from multiple posts

Tags: discussion

Consider the tag `tap` on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tap

The wiki clearly says "Test Anything Protocol (TAP)", but there are many posts which use the tag `tap` when they really should use the tag `touch` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/touch

Is there an easy way to select multiple posts and change the tag on those?  There are some questions which should be under tap, so just suggesting a synonym doesn't actually solve the problem.

Comment: add a "feature-request" tag here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any automated way or tool you can use to do this.

Usually whenever we need a tag cleanup someone starts a thread on meta, and a bunch of people pitch in and help out. Even a relatively small group (5-10) people can cleanup a mid sized tag reasonably well.

Comment: Not sure moderator can "delete a tag altogether". Where did you see such a thing mentioned or explained?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Huh. I was under the impression that moderators could. If not mods, then maybe community managers? I do remember reading somewhere that some level of users could nuke tags immediately. Can't seem to find that post right now though.

Comment: Developers maybe, but don't think it's used often if at all.